# Iterating through formula with varying parameters?

Tags: python, simulation, physics

I'm writing some code that does calculations on the interactions between two particles in a fluid. The main formula to get the new position relies on 3 other functions that get the necessary components for the formula.

The formula is basically:

```
new position = old position + Important_matrix * Important_Force + (other force)^2
```

This is the basic layout of my code:

```
initial position of particle 1 = [1,1,1]
initial position of particle 2 = [2,2,2]

def GetImportantMatrix(position of first particle, position of second particle):
'code here'
return the_important_matrix

def GetImportantForce(the_important_matrix):
'code here'
return important_force

def GetOtherForce():
'code here'
return other_force

def getnewposition(initial position of part. 1, initial position of part. 2, the_important_matrix, important_force, other_force, iterations):

???
```

My actual question is: **how do I implement the formula into the function so that it automatically calls the other functions to get the variables it needs, while updating after each iteration?** For example, how would I go about calling the other functions to make sure the current function gets the information it needs, and correctly updates each time.

I've seen some examples of this being done in other code snippets I've seen but I wasn't able to figure out how to apply that to my code since the position variable changes each time, and that also makes the other variables change each time.

I hope that makes sense? I'm very new to Python and still learning, if you guys can point me to any resources that would help with this I'll be thankful.

Comment: i didnt quite understand what you mean, can you further explain this line please `the position variable changes each time, and that also makes the other variables change each time`

Comment: Call each function, assign the return value to a variable, use the variables on the final equation.

Answer (score 0):

your code for getnewposition can look something like this

```
def getnewposition(pos1, pos2):
    importantMatrix = getImportantMatrix(pos1,pos2)
    return pos + importantMatrix + getImportantForce(importantMatrix) + pow(getOtherForce(),2)
```

Then for your main code, all you need to call is getnewposition with your position variables as your arguments whenever you need to.

or something like that. I'm not really sure what you meant so if you clarify I might be able to help more.

Comment: First off, thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

I tried your approach but unfortunately got a dimension error, since the quantities I'm working with are arrays.  Right now I'm getting the iPython error: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (1,6).`

Comment: I tried to edit my earlier comment, but I took too long. I copied it directly from the edit I tried to made:

Edit: Forgot to add the rest of the message.

How do I know which variables Numpy is saying can't be broadcast together because of that size? As in, how do I know which of the variables (or even which operation, multiplication or addition) it can't perform because of the dimension error?

Comment: manually troubleshoot it, eliminate things one a time until it does run then add them back together